# node-sass and gyp in docker on alpine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker or docker-compose file for a react project that has node-sass.
I have tried this and almost all solution on here but none of them is working.

```
FROM node:10.17.0-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base g++ make python

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

 // This is where node-sass is failing

CMD ["sh"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using the alpine version which does not come with node-sass. Use the full node image.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you means 'jessie" version? I tried that but the size of image is very large. 700MB and after installing packages about 1.4GB.

Comment: Use FROM node:10

Comment: this is even bigger. like 1GB the image and after installing packages 1.67GB